# Canonicalize in kdc-options is automatically set to true in Windows

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, java-ee-8

I have recently written a piece of code with JavaEE8 that authenticates users, requesting services from an application server, using Kerberos in an Active Directory domain. This includes a process which uses a keytab file to authenticate the server against the kdc of the target domain.
Everything works fine when using current systems but now I have to authenticate the server using a kdc that's running on Windows 2008 Server. 
I struggled with the `java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)` for a while now and finally figured out the problem:
The KDC on the Windows 2008 machine apparently doesn't yet support *RFC 6806 - Section 11 FAST scheme (ENC-PA-REP flag)* and thus the client must not use the kdc-option `canonicalize=true`.
Although the default value for canonicalize should be false (according to [MIT Kerberos Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#realms)) it is in fact set to true all the time when using a windows machine as the client. 
This can be seen by tracking the network traffic with wireshark and looking in the AS-REQ under *req-body --> kdc-options --> canonicalize*.
Interestingly enough this **only** occurs in Windows. When using Linux as a client canonicalize is set to false by default and everything works just fine.
I tried adding every setting I could find which bears any reference to canonicalization to the *krb5.conf* used by my client, but nothing actually changed the canonicalized kdc-option as seen in the AS-REQ. 
 
So there seems to be some setting in Windows specifically that overrides the canonicalize kdc-option to always be true. 
If anyone has any idea as to what that may be and how I could possibly change that behaviour I would be ever so thankfull!

Here's what my krb5.conf libdefaults section currently looks like:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = [our realm name]
  dns_lookup = false 
  dns_lookup_kdc = false  
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts rc4-hmac
  default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts
  permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts
  canonicalize = false
  dns_canonicalize_hostname = false
  rdns = false
```

**EDIT:**
I now also tried to set the `kdc_default_options = 0x00000000` in the krb5.conf file. This is the value that is set by default when running on Linux, whilst on Windows it is always set to `00010000`. (The difference is that the canonicalize parameter within the kdc-options is set to true with `00010000`).
Sadly enough this didn't change a thing. Neither did adding this Parameter with `00010000` to the Linux Version. Which makes me wonder if these Parameters from the krb5.conf are actually even used.
I know that the ones describing the domain, realm, kdc and encryption types are in fact used from that file but the rest of them don't really seem to have any impact whatsoever.
Does anyone have any experience with this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exact the same problem.

After much debugging, I solved by setting the system property

```
sun.security.krb5.disableReferrals=true
```

In this way, request is not canonicalized.

Comment: Probably related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223172

Comment: This actually works, thank you so much! 
It is even a perfect solution for my purposes because it can be set on a per application server basis depending on the Version of the Windows Server running the KDC.

Comment: Happy that you find it useful.

Comment: The flag is used here in code: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/20f3576cd1bbe516360b0d9f7deaacdad94df4d7/src/java.security.jgss/share/classes/sun/security/krb5/internal/CredentialsUtil.java#L331

`serviceCredsReferrals()` basically runs a referral loop by calling `serviceCredsSingle()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it fixed by downgrade enctypes (java 11.0.11 + minikdc + win10)

```
default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac
default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts
permitted_enctypes = aes128-cts
```

Comment: I am quite sure I tried this approach in our setting but sadly it did not work for me.
I can't however retry this because, thankfully, by now our customer has updated the Windows version on their KDC from 2008R2 to something newer where the problem doesn't persist.

Answer (score 0):

For me was helped the krb5.conf in <JAVA_HOME>/conf/security/krb5.conf
with body

```
[libdefaults]
    canonicalize = true
        default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts
        default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts
        permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts aes128-cts
        allow_weak_crypto = true
```

ps. Windows server 2017 + java17 + jcifs 2.17